# Difference of $\int_\mathbb R |f|^p d\mu$ and $(\int_\mathbb R |f| d\mu)^p $

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, inequality

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb R$. Let $f$ be in $L^p(\mu)$ for $p > 1$. We know from Jensen's inequality that

$$\int_\mathbb R |f|^p d\mu \geq \left(\int_\mathbb R |f| d\mu\right)^p .$$

Is there any way to get an upper bound for how much these two quantities can differ? i.e. are there any known inequalities of the form

$$\int_\mathbb R |f|^p d\mu - \left(\int_\mathbb R |f| d\mu\right)^p \leq (\text{something in terms of } f\text{ and }\mu)?$$

Also, in the case where $p=2$, the quantity on the left above is the variance of $|f|$. Is there an interesting interpretation for other values of $p$?

Comment: Nope, there isn't. Hint : consider functions of the form $f(x)=\epsilon$ if $0<x < M$, 0 otherwise.

Comment: In fact the ratio between these quantities may be arbitrary large.

Comment: I would be okay with an upper bound in terms of $f$ and $\mu$; perhaps some function of other $L^p$ norms of $f$.

Comment: @user15464 Such a bound does exist, and the best I know is $$\int_\mathbb{R}|f|^pd\mu-\left(\int_\mathbb{R}|f|^pd\mu\right)^p$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking whether a function $F$ of $f$ and $\mu$ such that $F(f,\mu)\geq \int|f|^pd\mu-\left|\int fd\mu\right|^p$ for all $f$, but $F(f,\mu):=\int|f|^pd\mu-\left|\int fd\mu\right|^p$ is allowed, and it's the best we can do.

What is interesting is too see how big can the ratio $R(f):=\frac{\int|f|^pd\mu}{\left|\int fd\mu\right|^p}$. If $\mu$ is a Borel measure absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, take $A_n:=(-\infty,-n)\cup(n,+\infty)$. Then $\mu(A_n)$ is decreasing to $0$ and taking $f:=\chi_{A_n}$ we get $R(A_n)=\mu(A_n)^{1-p}$ which converges to $+\infty$ since $1-p<0$ and $\mu(A_n)\to 0$.

For integers values of $p$, the integer of the $p$-th power is called $p$-th moment.